# Why MongoDB Node.js driver does not complain about a wrong replica set?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-replication

I'm just curious about the fact that the native driver doesn't complain about my (not properly configured) replica set. In fact my setup has just one instance of `mongod` listening on port 27021 (ports 27018 and 27019 ar not even used):

```
var async          = require('async')
  , mongodb        = require('mongodb')
  , Db             = mongodb.Db
  , Connection     = mongodb.Connection
  , Server         = mongodb.Server
  , ReplSetServers = mongodb.ReplSetServers;

async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        var rls = new ReplSetServers([
            new Server('localhost', 27017, {}), // Just mongod instance
            new Server('localhost', 27018, {}), // Offline
            new Server('localhost', 27019, {}), // Offline
        ]);

        new Db('test', rls, { w: 0 }).open(function (err, db) {
            callback(err, db);
        });
    },
], function (err, db) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    if (db) db.close();
});
```

No errors outputted. Of course stopping the only instance of `mongod` running causes a connection error. Am I'm missing something obvious here?

Comment: The list of servers provided to the driver is used to discover your replica set members. If the driver can connect to at least one replica, it will perform an rs.isMaster() call (you can try this in the shell) which returns a list of active members. As long as the operations performed do not violate the current state of the set (like trying to write when there is no primary) then you won't see an error. Even for the write, you will have to ask for acknowledgement (w :1) to get an error.

Comment: @JamesWahlin thank you for the explanation. Feel free to write an answer. When connecting to a real replica set I'm having a issue with closing the connection. It does not work, the connection remains opened and node script does not terminate. Can you help me fixing this problem?

Comment: I would suggest posting a new question on this. I am not familiar enough with the node.js driver to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of servers provided to the driver is used to discover your replica set members. If the driver can connect to at least one replica, it will perform an rs.isMaster() call (you can try this in the shell) which returns a list of active members. As long as the operations performed do not violate the current state of the set (like trying to write when there is no primary) then you won't see an error. Even for the write, you will have to ask for acknowledgement (w: >= 1) to see the error on the client.